# Android socket stable communication

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, connection, message

I am  working on Android project which communicates over TCP/IP. Communication works on specific protocol - this protocol is message oriented.

1. android device sends message to server via socket
2. server sends answer message to android device

It is not problem but I have a few parlous questions.

I don't have any idea how to solve connection interrupts (wifi, edge, change wifi to edge over open socket, ...) and connection timeouts? If android device sends 1 message and in this moment are connection problems - then android device sends different message (other request) - it is guaranteed that answers will be delivered in correct sequence?

I tried set timeout for socket object but it didn't work. I dont know why but if I set timeout to 5 seconds and I turned off the server before I sent message - it took more than 5 second before she came exciption.

I didn't found any articles on internet about this problems.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you talking about UDP or TCP sockets? The works around are different depending on the one you choose.

Comment: I am talking about TCP sockets. I mean UDP is easier for this but protocol works via TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For TCP sockets the way you can get timeouts is by using select() or poll(),in Android you have to use SocketChannel() ([java.nio](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html)) class to deal with non-blocking sockets. They both can query a socket for a specific period (10 or 20 seconds for example) and can tell you if it is writeable (you can use send()) or readable (there is data to be read recv()). Also the select() command will tell you if the socket has an error, most probably a broken connection. When you get such an error (except an interrupted signal, this one should be ignored and reissue the select), all you can do is close the socket and reopen a new one with the server, there is no way, as far as I know, to recover a broken connection, although, if you've implemented in the protocol, you can resume where you left off when the socket was broken. I don't know how you've implemented the protocol, but most of them will required a positive ACK (acknowledge) from the receiver before going on with another message. Also, when establishing a connection the client should specified if it a brand new connection or a broken one and act accordingly.

The idea is:

The sender sends a header specifying the command to process and the length of the data it's going to send after the header, the receiver receives the header and the data, once it process it, it sends a response ACK packet to the sender with a positive value to acknowledge the message, optionally with some data in case it's necessary. If after a reasonable period of time you don't receive the ACK packet then you may resend the same data again until you receive the positive ACK.

There could be the situation where the client sends a message, the server receives it and processes it, but when the server sends the positive ACK packet the connections breaks and the client never receives the packet, so it will resend the same message again once the connections is reestablished. To avoid this situation, it's necessary to send a message ID (an int which increments for every message sent) in the header to identity it.

I know it sounds difficult and it's in fact. If the connection is on the same network (intranet) it works nicely but, when the communication is on the internet, you may face a lot of problems and situations which you can't control, so it's necessary a well defined protocol where you can recover from broken connections and the transactions/messages won't be duplicated.